# Reading .txt file into pandas with empty entries in several columns

Tags: python, pandas, split, txt

I am trying to parse the txt file into readable pandas format.

See this sample .txt file.

```
Arsenal     123                             UK
Barcelona   456    Marc-Andre Ter Stegen    ES
Chelsea     789    Ceasr Azpilicueta        UK
```

from this .txt file, the file clearly stated three columns despite a name is missing in Arsenal.

I tried to load this .txt file into pandas and then I used str.split with more than one space command to try to separate the columns. However, the country code UK would fall to column 3 instead.

Below is my desired output:

```
|Arsenal   |123|NAN                  |UK|
|Barcelona |456|Marc-Andre Ter Stegen|ES|
|Chelsea   |789|Cesar Azpilicueta    |UK|
```

Comment: Can you change the input file? Pandas is looking for a separator between column values.

Comment: the input file cannot be reformatted as the original data is intended for SQL . so that's the challenging bits

Comment: However something i do know is that there are defined number of characters per each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [read_fwf (fix width format)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html?highlight=read_f#pandas.read_fwf) to read in the file

```
# to read in a dataframe
df=pd.read_fwf(r'csv2.txt', header=None) 
df
```

```
         0        1     2                       3
0   Arsenal     123     NaN                     UK
1   Barcelona   456     Marc-Andre Ter Stegen   ES
2   Chelsea     789     Ceasr Azpilicueta       UK
```

```
# to write to a CSV
(pd.read_fwf(r'csv2.txt', header=None)
 .fillna('NAN')
 .to_csv('out.csv', sep='|', header=None))
```

```
0|Arsenal|123|NAN|UK
1|Barcelona|456|Marc-Andre Ter Stegen|ES
2|Chelsea|789|Ceasr Azpilicueta|UK
```

PS: you can also pass colspec like following, describing from-to for each column

```
#colspecs = [(0, 6), (8, 20), (21, 33), (34, 43)]
```

Comment: Amazing it works!!! Thanks a lot. Never think of this arguement before!

Comment: However, i think the colspec is needed for better parsing. i am trying to understand that the colspec is per character based?

Comment: For example when i parse the term "Marc-Andre Ter Stegen", it is parsed as "arc-Andre Ter Stegen" . The a is stripped whilst others are preserved

e.g., I know the column zero the maximum character allowed is 9;column 1 is 3; column 2 is 21 and column 3 is 2.

Comment: documentation link. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html?highlight=read_fwf#pandas.read_fwf
*colspecslist of tuple (int, int) or ‘infer’. optional
    A list of tuples giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., [from, to[ ). String value ‘infer’ can be used to instruct the parser to try detecting the column specifications from the first 100 rows of the data which are not being skipped via skiprows (default=’infer’).*